# PHP if - else - else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

```
<html>
    <input type='text' name='mobile phone' value='
        <?php if (strpos($phone_number, '07') === 0) {
            echo $phone_number;
        } else {
            echo $alt_phone;
        }?>'
</html>
```

Works fine.  I would like to combine the above with:

```
    <?php if (!empty($alt_phone)) {
        echo $alt_phone;
    } else {
        echo '07777777777';
    }?>'`
```

I have tried `ELSEIF` with the new condition, and a completely separate `<?php ?>` section and both times I get a blank page, instead of a textbox with a telephone number in it.

I am trying to achieve this: If $phone_number is a mobile, enter this number, otherwise enter the `alt_phone`, unless `$alt_phone` is blank, then enter '07777777777'.

Comment: Please show the attempt using `elseif`. It should work when you use it like this `if (strpost(...) === 0) { } elseif (!empty($alt_phone)) { } else { }`

Comment: "and both times I get a blank page" - have you tried [turning on error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851)?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php 
if (!empty($phone_number)) {
echo $phone_number;
}
elseif(!empty($alt_phone)) 
{
echo $alt_phone;
}
else{
echo '07777777777';
 }
?>'`
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
<?php 

if (strpos($phone_number, '07') === 0) {
    echo $phone_number;
} 
else if (!empty($alt_phone)) {
    echo $alt_phone;
} 
else {
   echo '07777777777';
}
?>
```